# bash change directory from script with menu

Tags: bash

how can i make this script actually change the directory i'm in?

so the script just takes some options from a database
then after i select the one i want, it doesn't work
i also tried running the script with source but still nothing..

```
    #!/bin/bash
    options=( $(mysql --skip-column-names -uroot -pmypass all_dbs -e "select path from databases_table WHERE locked != 0 ") )

    read_list(){
    echo ""
    PS3="Change directory to:"
    select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit" ; do
        if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#options[@]} )) ; then
            exit
        elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) ; then
            chosen="$opt"
            break
        else
            echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
        fi
    done
    }

    changeto_entry(){
    mysql -uroot -pmypass --skip-column-names all_dbs -e "select name,\`database\`,path from databases_table where locked != 0 AND name = '$chosen'" | while read name database path; do
        cd $path
    done
    }

    read_list
    changeto_entry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to `cd` in a subshell created by a pipeline. Here's a simpler test case exhibiting the same problem:

```
true | cd /
```

To fix it, you can rewrite the pipe (`cmd | while read; do ..; done`) to use redirection from process substitution instead (`while read; do ..; done <   <(cmd)`):

```
changeto_entry(){
  while read _ _ path
  do
    cd "$path"
  done  <   <(mysql -uroot -pmypass --skip-column-names all_dbs -e "select name,\`database\`,path from databases_table where locked != 0 AND name = '$chosen'")
}
```

Now, if your `mysql` command is correct, sourcing the file will change the directory.

Comment: +1 This is (almost certainly) the right answer.  I kind of glazed over the pipe at the end of the long line.  Of course the script will need to be `source`d as well.

Answer (score 0):

The current working directory will be for the script, not for you. i.e. your terminal user will just go back to normal after it executes.

Comment: is there any way to make it change my directory ?

Comment: I don't know of one, but imagine if every script you ran moved you around your filesystem, because the author forgot to put you back. pretty annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Your script may work if you `source` it instead of run it as a normal script:

```
source ./mycdscript.sh
```

This will have the effect of evaluating the commands in script within the same shell as your bash prompt.

Be careful though, as any variables/functions set/defined in the script will still be defined in your prompt shell.

Comment: Are you sure the `$path` variable is getting set?  Can you `echo` its value from within the `while` loop?

Comment: i used echo "cd $path" and i see it\s getting set

Comment: i encourage you to try the script - maybe replace the mysql with some array... it's very strange

Comment: Can you provide samples of what the `options` array might be set to, and sample output from the 2nd `mysql` command?